# Is there a mongo equivalent of INSERT INTO SELECT

Tags: mongodb

We want to start putting data into history collections in Mongodb.

In MySQL I would use an

```
INSERT INTO SELECT fields FROM ....
```

Is there an equivalent in Mongo?

Comment: Have you checked out [$merge](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/)

Comment: You can find your information in MongoDB Manual: [SQL to Aggregation Mapping Chart](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/).